# In a multi-module project, can a maven module access transitive test-scoped dependencies of another module it depends on?

Tags: unit-testing, maven, dependencies, multi-module

I have a multi-module Maven+Spring project. Some modules depend on other modules.

Let's say we have a module named `services` that depends on the module named `persistence`.

The services module :

- At Spring level, imports the `persistence` context
- At Maven level, depends on the `persistence` module

The `persistence` module defines some configuratrion related to the... persistence : datasource, JPA, transactions...

It has some dependencies for testing the DB (JDBC drivers, DBCP, H2) that are limited to the test scope, since when the app is deployed, the DataSource will defined in the container (Tomcat) and accessed via JNDI.

Now, I would like to have access, during the Maven test phase of the `services` module, to the test-scoped (transitive) dependencies of the `persistence` module.

The [Maven manual (Table 3.1)](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html) say that normally, test-scope dependencies are not available transitively.

Is it  possible to obtain them somehow in the context of a multi-module project ?

If not what are good alternatives ? (Define the test dependencies in the parent pom ?... )

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found exactly how it should work, i.e. by **generating a test JAR**, which is a type of artifact, in the module that is used as a dependency by the other, in our example the persistence module :

```
<build>
    <plugins>

            <!-- Generate test jar too -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then by declaring this test jar as a test scoped dependency of the other module, in our example the `services` module :

```
<!-- Services module -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>services</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>services</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note the second dependency that is identical to the first except for the `type` that is set to `test-jar` and for the `scope` that is set to test.

Now, you would imagine that the **tests written in the `service` module would have access to the test classes of the `persistence` module** (**this works**) but also to the test scoped dependencies of the persistence module.

However, it is a known issue (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-1378) that it doesn't work that way. It's been open since 2005, so I don't see it fixed in a near future... but who knows.

Si I will just have to duplicate the test-scoped dependencies on both modules, or just define them in the parent pom...

Comment: Thanks for this, just spent an hour wondering why I was getting class not found exception :(

Comment: THANK YOU!! For what it's worth, I didn't need to include the dependency for the main module artifact, just the `<scope>test</scope>` one, but other people's mileage may vary, of course. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is *should* but it doesn't.  It happens with provided scope too.  Issue logged here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5255

Comment: Thank you but the issue you pointed to, while related, does not  answer my question. Actually it is almost the opposite problem they are having there : transitive dependencies of test/provided dependencies are included in the final JAR.

Comment: Sorry! tl;dr :)  We ran into the test scope transitive dependencies not being in the unit test classpath just the other day so when I saw your question, I just assumed it was the same issue.

Comment: Is some other module declaring these as non-test scope dependencies?  Get the effective POM (via eclipse or help plugin) to see.