# Reuse resources and context in another project

Tags: spring, junit, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I have a project as following:

```
Project
    Project-A/
        src/test/java/
            someTests.java
        src/test/resources
            database/
                create.sql
                insert.sql
            spring/
                test-config.xml
    project-B/
        src/test/java
            otherTests.java
```

*pom.xml* of Project-B:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And in *someTests.java*, my configuration is:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webapp-config.xml", "classpath:spring/test-dao-config.xml" })
public class DacsDAOImplTest
```

I want to reuse *test-config.xml*, *create.sql* and *insert.sql* in *otherTests.java*.

I have already tried in otherTests.java

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:spring/test-dao-config.xml"})
```

But this doesn't seem to work...

**Edit**: Geoand's answer help, I have no more exception related to beans, but now I have a

> FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [exception-messages.properties] cannot be opened because it does not
>   exist.

Since I don't understand exactly what changes have done, I don't know how to fix this...
exception-messages are used in *webapp-config.xml* as `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:exception-messages.properties" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that although you are importing Project-A into Project-B, the of test code does not get included by Maven. Check out the solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816805/in-a-multi-module-project-can-a-maven-module-access-transitive-test-scoped-depe) SO question to see if it helps at all

**EDIT:**

Once you get maven to be to import the test code as well, you will need to create .properties files under /test/resources that contain the test values of the properties you are using in the application